# What happened to com.vaadin.application?

Tags: vaadin, deprecated

Currently I need to build a awfully old project. After a few frustrating hours I decided to update the pom.xml to a state-of-the-art one. Of course I've changed the vaadin version while doing so. I've raised it from 6.8.12 to 7.6.7.

Not suprprisingly I've a lot of "cannot be resolved to a type" errors now. One of them is "Application cannot be resolved to a type." The import comes from "com.vaadin.application". I've never heard of this class and can find barely any information. What happend to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While most APIs remain compatible, there have been many changes between the 2 versions, and the `Application` itself has been replaced by `com.vaadin.ui.UI`. Below an excerpt from the official [*migrating from Vaadin 6 to 7 guide*](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Migrating+from+Vaadin+6+to+Vaadin+7):

> The first code change that applies to every Vaadin 6 application
>   concerns the **com.vaadin.Application** class - it exists **no more**. The
>   main entry point to your application is now a **com.vaadin.ui.UI**, which
>   replaces Application and its main window. When switching to UI, you
>   also get [multi-window support](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-sub-window.html) out of the box, so bye bye to any old
>   hacks to make it work. On the flip side, a new UI is created on page
>   reload. If you prefer to keep the UI state over page reloads in the
>   same way Vaadin 6 does, just add [**@PreserveOnRefresh**](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+an+application+that+preserves+state+on+refresh) annotation on your
>   UI class.